# fake directory for different countries

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i'm really stuck with this problem, and have no idea where to start.

URLs (rewrite):

```
http://www.website.com
http://www.website.com/au/
http://www.website.com/uk/
http://www.website.com/products 
http://www.website.com/uk/products
http://www.website.com/au/products
```

Actual URLs:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php
http://www.website.com/index.php?co=au
http://www.website.com/index.php?co=uk
http://www.website.com/products.php
http://www.website.com/products.php?co=uk 
http://www.website.com/products.php?co=au
```

Is there a way to create this? (country codes are only 2 letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solutions are inflexible solutions, but it can be sources of your inspiration.

```
# This directive make effect to http://www.website.com -> http://www.website.com/index.php rule.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(au|uk)/$     http://www.website.com/index.php?co=$1       [QSA,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/products$     http://www.website.com/products.php          [QSA,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/uk/products$  http://www.website.com/products.php?co=uk    [QSA,P,L]
```

If you add the country codes dynamically, try the following snippets.
And more informations are here [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html]

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap  contry_code txt:conf/extra/contry_code.list
# ${contry_code:$1|au} some description is here; au is default value if non-mached 
RewriteRule ^/([a-z][a-z])/$     http://www.website.com/index.php?co=${contry_code:$1|au} [QSA,P,L]
```

"contry_code.list" file format

```
# column1: using code for match, column2: return value
au au
uk uk
jp jp
```

Comment: Thanks Daein, How can I make the country code dynamic? there will be around 26 countries in the system

Comment: I added the more patterns. Try it and I wish it to be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks again Daen, is there a way without using RewriteMap? I'm sorry for asking you so many questions, i really appreciate your help

Comment: If you would check the country codes into php side, you need not to use RewriteMap. e.g.> `RewriteRule ^/[a-z][a-z]/$ http://www.website.com/index.php?co=$1 [QSA,P,L]`

Comment: above example has some typo, ^/([a-z][a-z])/$ needed braces into slashes. :)